# how to open a formatted text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

i need to open a text file in matlab that is similar to this:

```
(1.234,2.345,3.456)
(1.111,2.222,3.333)
(5.432,4.321,5.432)
```

I've tried `dlmread`, `fscanf`, and `importdata` but none of them seem to work.  I'm trying to read this file into a 3x3 array, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Can you show us the `fscanf` code that you actually tried?

Comment: For that matter, show all your attempts and explain in detail what is the problem with each one.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: updated for data fields being separated by newlines*

Here's an inelegant solution, assuming the text file is called `test.txt` in the current directory.

```
% Read the text file into a string:
    txt = fileread('test.txt');
% Split the string at white space:
    A = strsplit(txt,'\n'); 
% Remove brackets:
    B = cellfun(@(x) x(2:end-1),A,'uniformoutput',0); 
% Split groups by commas:
    C = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,','),B,'uniformoutput',0);
% Convert entries from string to double:
    D = cellfun(@(x) cellfun(@str2num,x),C','uniformoutput',0); 
% Convert from cell to one big matrix:
    NumArray = cell2mat(D);
```

The output is

```
NumArray =

    1.2340    2.3450    3.4560
    1.1110    2.2220    3.3330
    5.4320    4.3210    5.4320
```